# ZF2 - Register custom form element

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I've overridden the Text element with my own (call it `My\Form\Element\Text`). Now I want to make it so that when I add a text element to the form, it defaults to my overridden class and not `Zend\Form\Element\Text`:

```
$this->add([
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'to',
]);
```

I know that I could use `'type' => 'My\Form\Element\Text'` instead of just `'type' => 'text'`, but I'm trying to find out if I can avoid that and just use the custom element by default.

I've tried both of these techniques:

**module.config.php**

```
return [
    'form_elements' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'text' => 'My\Form\Element\Text',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Module.php**

```
class Module {

    public function getFormElementConfig() {
        return [
            'invokables' => [
                'text' => 'My\Form\Element\Text',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Neither of these worked (still getting an instance of `Zend\Form\Element\Text`). Is there some other way of registering the element so that the `Zend\Form\Factory::create()` method creates an instance of my custom element instead of the Zend version?

Comment: If you're creating a new instance of the form factory yourself and then calling its create method, you need to pass the `FormElementManager` service to its constructor to have it use your custom elements.

Comment: @Crisp: I don't create an instance of the form factory myself, `Zend\Form\Form` does that in its `getFormFactory()` method, which is called from its `add()` method. I could do this in the form: `$this->getFormFactory()->getFormElementManager()->setInvokableClass('text', 'My\Form\Element\Text');`, but I would have to do that on each form I make. I want it to be done automatically on every form. I suppose I could extend `Zend\Form\Form` with an abstract and have each of my individual forms extend that, but I was trying to see if there was an easier way, like the examples of what I tried.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just taking a guess at a possible reason. What you've tried so far should have worked, at least according to the docs here -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements. You should pay heed to the warning that you must use the form element manager to fetch your forms though.

Comment: @Crisp: Thank you for the link. I searched all over, dunno how I missed that. That links mentions two catches, and I wasn't following either of them. If you want to post that as your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: no probs, and done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your config is correct, there are a couple of gotchas to be aware of when using custom elements, [detailed in the docs here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements)

Catch 1

> If you are creating your form class by extending Zend\Form\Form, you must not add the custom element in the __construct-or, but rather in the init() method

Catch 2

> You must not directly instantiate your form class, but rather get an instance of it through the Zend\Form\FormElementManager